# Get GPU info within Electron app

Tags: javascript, gpu, electron

I'd like to know how can I retrieve GPU info within Electron app.

I would like to get the same info as when I type in the browser `chrome://gpu/` and log this information for diagnostics.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For now, you can [load `chrome://gpu` and extract it using DOM operations.](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/663#issuecomment-87510978) There's no standard API for extracting that information.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#appgetgpuinfoinfotype

```
const electron = require('electron');
electron.app.getGPUInfo('complete').then(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpu-info

```
const gpuInfo = require('gpu-info');
gpuInfo().then(function(data) {
    console.log('GPUS:', data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading in 2020, to get the info in chrome://gpu in recent Electron you want `app.getGPUFeatureStatus()` https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#appgetgpufeaturestatus

`app.getGPUInfo('complete')` provides some interesting info but not the same as chrome://gpu